# Possible to use AutoQuery to find NULL values?

Tags: c#, servicestack

I have a standard ServiceStack API with AutoQuery. I'd like to make a query for items that have a `NULL` value in a property. I've tried specifying the field with no value, but that pulls no results. I've also tried `MyProperty=NULL` along with a bunch of variations. No dice.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

`https://myapi.com/api/foos?Bar=NULL` or even `https://myapi.com/api/foos?Bar=`

I would like to avoid putting a field in my request object just to enable this, as there are several properties I'd like to do this for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for querying for `null` was [added in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/ca4abdb302095008703513d50f62ed60596365df) which now lets you search for null with an empty queryString value, e.g: `/foos?Bar=`

This change is available from v4.0.51+ that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: When using the JsonServiceClient, this works fine where the nullable parameter is a string, because you can set it to string.Empty and it gets appended to the Url. But I can't see how to make this work with a nullable value type (e.g. say I want to QueryDb<Order> where DiscountId is null (type nullable Long, for example)... the DiscountId is not appended as an empty query parameter in the same way that an empty string is? Is there a neat way to do this, or do i have to append the DiscountId manually somehow? In my case, I'm querying table A, joining B, where B.Id is null (no mapped record yet)

Comment: @DaleHolborow there's no easy way to specify an empty string for a nullable value type but it should be possible with a [Customized Url Filter](http://docs.servicestack.net/routing#customize-urls-used-with-iurlfilter) on your AutoQuery Request DTO which will let you control and append to the QueryString that's sent.